# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de un tema en VSC?

Tags: vscode

Estoy usando el tema Winter is coming (dark black). No se si es posible cambiar el color que resalta y que sale cuando se selecciona una palabra, letra, variable, etc.

No se como llamarlo, pero es el recuadro que sale al hacer doble clic en una palabra.

Comment: creo que cambiar solo el color de la seleccion de texto es un poco mas rebuscado. Descargate temas de color y fijate uno en que te sientas comodo. En la esquina inferior izquierda boton administrar > tema de color > examinar temas de color. Podes descargar o elegir los que estan por defecto.

Comment: @ElFuturoLlego Logré dar con una solución, en el "workbench.colorCustomizations": {} se usan varias propiedades como:
 
"editor.selectionBackground": "#d23131", 
"editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#d23131", 
y 
"editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#d23131". 

El problema que tengo ahora es que al seleccionar una palabra, las demás que coninciden si se resaltan del color que quiero pero la que seleccioné pierde el color y agarra la del tema principal.